# Tabbar Application with camera

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, camera

I want to implement camera in a Tab Bar application. I have been able to make the camera appear but there is no capture button to capture the image. How can I customize the camera view so that the capture button appears?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should get an image like this. Clicking on the camera icon will take the photo.
Arn't you getting like this? Then check your UIImagePickerController and its delegates.

[image]

Comment: i am opened camera but the tabbar hides the Cancel and Image Buttons at bottom

Comment: I am opening in a tab bar controller, it works fine. you should post your corresponding view controller code.